# X-win launching the same application on a second client, the first client gets called

Tags: linux, firefox, ssh, cygwin, x11

I'm currently connected to my local server (LAN) via SSH and have opened Firefox. I'm using it to access a service running on said server but limited to the 127.0.0.1 space.

When I connect to a second server (WAN) again via SSH and open Firefox from there (I'm using the Cygwin/X server) the page I open is called by the first instance of Firefox (in a new tab). I'm calling the remote server's router at 192.168.1.1 but see my local router's page instead!

If I then close the original instance of Firefox, I get the remote server's router page as expected.

I hope this is clear and can provide extra info if needed.

What I'm expecting is to have two Firefox windows on my desktop, each one running on it's own server.

Thanks

Comment: Are you tunnelling the connection to that server through ssh? Since you can only access it at 127.0.0.1.... I'm not sure what you mean by "open Firefox from there [the second server]"

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su].

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-new-instance

Comment: Thanks @Kenster, I'll try there.

Comment: @JvO: I'm running the X server on my PC, connecting to the remote server via SSH and launching Firefox via SSH (using my PC as the display).
I repeat the operation on another remote server hoping to get two Firefox windows on my desktop (one per remote server) but getting instead a second tab on the first Firefox I open

Comment: @n.m. : interesting...